# Converting loop with condition into RxJava stream

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I have code that does blocking operation in while loop (downloads some data from a server). Client does not know how many items are going to be returned in each step. Loop breaks when N items are downloaded.

```
val n = 10
val list = ArrayList<T>()

while (list.size < n) {
    val lastItemId = list.last()?.id ?: 0
    val items = downloadItems(lastItemId)
    list.addAll(items)
}
```

`downloadItems` performs blocking HTTP call and returns list. Now let's assume `downloadItems` changes and new return type is `Observable<Item>`. How could I change the code to use RxJava without performing something like `blockingGet`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `repeatUntil` to achieve this:

```
var totalItems = 0    
var id = 0
Observable.fromCallable {
            downloadItems(id)
        }
        .flatMap {
            list ->
                totalItems += list.size
                id = list.last()?.id ?: 0
                Observable.just(list)
        }
        .repeatUntil({totalItems > n})
        .subscribe({result -> System.out.println(result) })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is elegant way

```
int n = 10;
Observable.range(0,n)
        .flatMap(i -> downloadItems(i))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(itemsList -> itemsList.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item)));
```

Comment: That would call downLoadItems 10 times. I just want to download 10 items. Each call of downloadItems could return more than 0 items, exact number of items is unknown.

Comment: I found question that is similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827046/using-flatmap-in-rxjava-2-x